# How do I prevent Office applications to update a SPListItem field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-word, ms-office, event-receiver

I have a document library in SharePoint whith a custom content type. There is one custom field that is set by an item added event receiver each time a new document is uploaded.

My problem occurs when someone opens a document with Word and uses the "save as" option in the Word menu to save a new document. My event receiver sets the correct value to my field and then Word is setting the field back to the old value again.

How can I prevent Word from changing my field ? The field is hidden, readonly and sealed.

I think I can catch the item updating event fired by Word. If there is a way to know that it is Word trying to change my item I could cancel the event. Is there a way?

Comment: is it an out of the box field or a custom field ?

Comment: It's a custom field defined in an elements.xml file and added by a site feature. It looks like this: <Field Type="Guid" DisplayName="MyDocumentId" Required="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" Group="Custom Columns" ID="{5d4295d3-33d7-46d4-b30c-fab9a13ee67e}" StaticName="MyDocumentId" Name="MyDocumentId" >

Comment: I changed the readonly and sealed properties with SharePoint Manager to see if it would prevent the changes by Word. But it didn't.